# WCF self hosting application and namespace reservation

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm new to WCF, trying to learn the basics.

I've created a simple C# console application that self hosts (by using the ServiceHost class) a simple service.

Whenever i attempt to run it, i get an exception regarding namespace reservation.

I've found some command (netsh) to prevent this from happening, however i am wondering if this is a must when self hosting a service?

I'd like to be able to deploy services ("agents") remotely on machines without doing massive amount of work, and be able to communicate with them.

Comment: post some code because I do the same as you do and never had any issue with namespaces... show code and error message :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not have to ensure compatibility with existing clients, one workaround could be to use a different **binding** for your service.  If you are not tied to http you could for example use **net.tcp** instead. This works without namespace reservation and does not require administrator privileges.

See [this chart](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2006/12/01/WCF-Binding-decision-chart.aspx) for the features provided by the different bindings

Answer (score 0):

The short cut would be to run your servicehost width administrator privileges. Once you want to host your services live, you should consider hosting them using IIS

Comment: I cannot rely and don't want to rely on IIs being there to host in it. that's why i am looking for an alternative option (Windows Service, simple application, etc).

Comment: if you are running the wcf host inside a console, you need to elevate it. if you are running the host inside a service, this will be done by assigning the correct exec-user. another nice side-effect: a stand-alone (wcf-)service isn't limited by IIS (when eg running on IIS 6 or lower you can bypass the nice 800mb-limit)

Comment: Just have in mind, that you´re missing reliability and monitoring features that IIS can offer you when you start building your own servicehost. Other than that, you already discovered how to enable your service user to be able to host a WCF Service.

Comment: the service will never be "live" in the sense that it's an internal organizational application that will never be exposed outside, and only be used inside our lab machines.